# How to integrate JSPM/SystemJS with ASP.Net MVC app?

Tags: aurelia, systemjs, jspm

We started looking at Aurelia to see how how we could integrate it into existing ASP.NET MVC app. Idea is that each "Area" in mvc app would become Aurelia app. Since our app is not being served from the root, how does one tell Aurelia where to look for js files. For example when running app it would be at http://localhhost/ngc but Aurelia is not able to load files as it looks for them at http://localhost dropping ngc, so it never finds any files.

Any help, is this something that one can set up in configuration or the app?

I get 404 for

```
http://localhost/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-bootstrapper@2.1.1.js
```

while it should really try to load it from

```
http://localhost/ngc/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-bootstrapper@2.1.1.js
```

Here is the configuration

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },
  baseURL:'http://localhost/ngc',
  map: {
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@2.1.1",
    "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@1.1.2",
    "aurelia-http-client": "npm:aurelia-http-client@1.1.1",
    "aurelia-validation": "npm:aurelia-validation@1.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "npm:font-awesome@4.7.0",
    "typescript": "npm:typescript@2.3.0",
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0": {
      "assert": "npm:assert@1.4.1"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1": {
      "buffer": "npm:buffer@5.0.6"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-constants@0.1.0": {
      "constants-browserify": "npm:constants-browserify@0.0.1"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0": {
      "crypto-browserify": "npm:crypto-browserify@3.11.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1": {
      "events": "npm:events@1.0.2"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-http@1.7.1": {
      "Base64": "npm:Base64@0.2.1",
      "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0",
      "url": "github:jspm/nodelibs-url@0.1.0",
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-net@0.1.2": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "http": "github:jspm/nodelibs-http@1.7.1",
      "net": "github:jspm/nodelibs-net@0.1.2",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0",
      "timers": "github:jspm/nodelibs-timers@0.1.0",
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.1.0": {
      "os-browserify": "npm:os-browserify@0.1.2"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0": {
      "path-browserify": "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2": {
      "process": "npm:process@0.11.9"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-querystring@0.1.0": {
      "querystring": "npm:querystring@0.2.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0": {
      "stream-browserify": "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-string_decoder@0.1.0": {
      "string_decoder": "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-timers@0.1.0": {
      "timers-browserify": "npm:timers-browserify@1.4.2"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-url@0.1.0": {
      "url": "npm:url@0.10.3"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0": {
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-vm@0.1.0": {
      "vm-browserify": "npm:vm-browserify@0.0.4"
    },
    "npm:asn1.js@4.9.1": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.6",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "minimalistic-assert": "npm:minimalistic-assert@1.0.0",
      "vm": "github:jspm/nodelibs-vm@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:assert@1.4.1": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-binding@1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@2.1.1": {
      "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.1",
      "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@1.1.2",
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-history-browser": "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.2",
      "aurelia-logging-console": "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.2.1",
      "aurelia-polyfills": "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.2.1",
      "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.4.1",
      "aurelia-templating-binding": "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-templating-resources": "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.4.0",
      "aurelia-templating-router": "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.1.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.1": {
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.1": {
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.3.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-framework@1.1.2": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.2.1",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.4.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0": {
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-http-client@1.1.1": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.2": {
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0": {
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0": {
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.3.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@1.1.0": {
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-router@1.3.0": {
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.1",
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-route-recognizer": "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@1.1.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.3.0": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.2.1",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.4.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.4.0": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.2.1",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.4.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.1.0": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.2.1",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.4.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating@1.4.1": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.2.1",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-validation@1.0.0": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.2.1",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.3.1",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.4.1"
    },
    "npm:bn.js@4.11.6": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1"
    },
    "npm:browserify-aes@1.0.6": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "buffer-xor": "npm:buffer-xor@1.0.3",
      "cipher-base": "npm:cipher-base@1.0.3",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "evp_bytestokey": "npm:evp_bytestokey@1.0.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:browserify-cipher@1.0.0": {
      "browserify-aes": "npm:browserify-aes@1.0.6",
      "browserify-des": "npm:browserify-des@1.0.0",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "evp_bytestokey": "npm:evp_bytestokey@1.0.0"
    },
    "npm:browserify-des@1.0.0": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "cipher-base": "npm:cipher-base@1.0.3",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "des.js": "npm:des.js@1.0.0",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1"
    },
    "npm:browserify-rsa@4.0.1": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.6",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "constants": "github:jspm/nodelibs-constants@0.1.0",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "randombytes": "npm:randombytes@2.0.3"
    },
    "npm:browserify-sign@4.0.4": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.6",
      "browserify-rsa": "npm:browserify-rsa@4.0.1",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "create-hmac": "npm:create-hmac@1.1.4",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "elliptic": "npm:elliptic@6.4.0",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "parse-asn1": "npm:parse-asn1@5.1.0",
      "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:buffer-xor@1.0.3": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:buffer@5.0.6": {
      "base64-js": "npm:base64-js@1.2.0",
      "ieee754": "npm:ieee754@1.1.8"
    },
    "npm:cipher-base@1.0.3": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0",
      "string_decoder": "github:jspm/nodelibs-string_decoder@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:constants-browserify@0.0.1": {
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:core-util-is@1.0.2": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1"
    },
    "npm:create-ecdh@4.0.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.6",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "elliptic": "npm:elliptic@6.4.0"
    },
    "npm:create-hash@1.1.2": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "cipher-base": "npm:cipher-base@1.0.3",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "ripemd160": "npm:ripemd160@1.0.1",
      "sha.js": "npm:sha.js@2.4.8"
    },
    "npm:create-hmac@1.1.4": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:crypto-browserify@3.11.0": {
      "browserify-cipher": "npm:browserify-cipher@1.0.0",
      "browserify-sign": "npm:browserify-sign@4.0.4",
      "create-ecdh": "npm:create-ecdh@4.0.0",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "create-hmac": "npm:create-hmac@1.1.4",
      "diffie-hellman": "npm:diffie-hellman@5.0.2",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "pbkdf2": "npm:pbkdf2@3.0.9",
      "public-encrypt": "npm:public-encrypt@4.0.0",
      "randombytes": "npm:randombytes@2.0.3"
    },
    "npm:des.js@1.0.0": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "minimalistic-assert": "npm:minimalistic-assert@1.0.0"
    },
    "npm:diffie-hellman@5.0.2": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.6",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "miller-rabin": "npm:miller-rabin@4.0.0",
      "randombytes": "npm:randombytes@2.0.3",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:elliptic@6.4.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.6",
      "brorand": "npm:brorand@1.1.0",
      "hash.js": "npm:hash.js@1.0.3",
      "hmac-drbg": "npm:hmac-drbg@1.0.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "minimalistic-assert": "npm:minimalistic-assert@1.0.0",
      "minimalistic-crypto-utils": "npm:minimalistic-crypto-utils@1.0.1",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:evp_bytestokey@1.0.0": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:font-awesome@4.7.0": {
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.33"
    },
    "npm:hash.js@1.0.3": {
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1"
    },
    "npm:hmac-drbg@1.0.1": {
      "hash.js": "npm:hash.js@1.0.3",
      "minimalistic-assert": "npm:minimalistic-assert@1.0.0",
      "minimalistic-crypto-utils": "npm:minimalistic-crypto-utils@1.0.1",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:inherits@2.0.1": {
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:miller-rabin@4.0.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.6",
      "brorand": "npm:brorand@1.1.0"
    },
    "npm:os-browserify@0.1.2": {
      "os": "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:parse-asn1@5.1.0": {
      "asn1.js": "npm:asn1.js@4.9.1",
      "browserify-aes": "npm:browserify-aes@1.0.6",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "evp_bytestokey": "npm:evp_bytestokey@1.0.0",
      "pbkdf2": "npm:pbkdf2@3.0.9",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:pbkdf2@3.0.9": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "create-hmac": "npm:create-hmac@1.1.4",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:process@0.11.9": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "vm": "github:jspm/nodelibs-vm@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:public-encrypt@4.0.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.6",
      "browserify-rsa": "npm:browserify-rsa@4.0.1",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "parse-asn1": "npm:parse-asn1@5.1.0",
      "randombytes": "npm:randombytes@2.0.3"
    },
    "npm:punycode@1.3.2": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:randombytes@2.0.3": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:readable-stream@1.1.14": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "core-util-is": "npm:core-util-is@1.0.2",
      "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "isarray": "npm:isarray@0.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "stream-browserify": "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0",
      "string_decoder": "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31"
    },
    "npm:ripemd160@1.0.1": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:sha.js@2.4.8": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:source-map-support@0.4.14": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1",
      "child_process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-child_process@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "module": "github:jspm/nodelibs-module@0.1.0",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "querystring": "github:jspm/nodelibs-querystring@0.1.0",
      "source-map": "npm:source-map@0.5.6"
    },
    "npm:source-map@0.5.6": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0": {
      "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "readable-stream": "npm:readable-stream@1.1.14"
    },
    "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.1"
    },
    "npm:timers-browserify@1.4.2": {
      "process": "npm:process@0.11.9"
    },
    "npm:typescript@2.3.0": {
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "net": "github:jspm/nodelibs-net@0.1.2",
      "os": "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.1.0",
      "source-map-support": "npm:source-map-support@0.4.14"
    },
    "npm:url@0.10.3": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
      "punycode": "npm:punycode@1.3.2",
      "querystring": "npm:querystring@0.2.0",
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:util@0.10.3": {
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:vm-browserify@0.0.4": {
      "indexof": "npm:indexof@0.0.1"
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in your `app module`. in method `configureRouter`, set `config.options.root` and base tag in your index.html with the same value. In your case it should be have a value of **/ngc**. See it [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/2).

Also you can use [bundling](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/bundling-jspm) to deploy your app in production without the need to set the `root` or `base` tag.